# Sending confirmation email to survey participant

Tags: email, confirmation

When a participant finishes their survey, I would like to send them an email confirmation that they responses to the survey was successfully saved.

I'm kind of stuck at the write-up of this confirmation email. Please advise.

**Subject**: Thank you

> Hi John Doe,
>
> This is to confirm that your response to the XXX Survey has been
>   saved.
>
> For more information, please email your queries to change@domain.org.
>
> Thank you.

Comment: Why not give them a box to tick asking whether they want the confirmation email ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would repeat into the email:

•   the name of the survey

•   the company that has released it

•   the link to check again the answers provided

•   to know where those will be saved and used for

•   a general contact for any information

In the end, it would be nice signed it with a real name that increase the trust of the users.

---

Good Morning / Good afternoon / Good evening John Doe,

Thanks for participating to the **XXX Survey** created by **XXXX**.

It has been submitted and stored correctly into our XXXX database.

To review your answers please click on **[Review Survey Response][1]**.

Please for more information and new enquiries write an email to **conchange@domain.org**.

Regards,

James
Survey team XXX

Comment: A timed salutation ("_Good morning..._" etc.) is probably not appropriate, as you don't know when the user will be reading it (not everyone will be reading the email within minutes of sending it). A generic "_Hello John Doe_" may be better.

Comment: The email could be shorter using the sentence "Thanks for participating to the XXX Survey created by XXXX" as subject line and greeting with Hello as suggested, but if use this than pay attention to the closing line using Cheers and not Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Jeffery,
I would include the persons responses where possible. This gives the respondent confidence in their interactions with you.

It's not always applicable. For example: a survey of a few pages with multi selects and grids would be a real challenge to shove into the body of an email and is not worth the effort. OTOH, if it's a weekly form to fill out for who wants what from the group lunch order, to include "You ordered pasta on Sunday, pizza on Tuesday, _______ on ________, etc" is both doable and well worth the investment.

Comment: Depending on the content of the survey, emailing the user's responses may not be appropriate (e.g. if it contained personal, medical or financial information).

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

What is the point of spamming your users with trivial email messages? Instead, simply show  them a short confirmation message on the device and system they used to fill in the survey. Sending email messages gives your users indirect feedback through extra steps (for basically nothing).

Depending on the context, your confirmation message really doesn't have to be any more complex than something like the following:

> Thanks for filling in our survey, your results have been saved. Please contact us at change@domain.org if you have any questions about this survey.